# How can I restrict comments on Wordpress, so only the POST AUTHOR and the user who commented can see them?

Tags: functions, customization

I'm after a way to hide / restrict FRONTEND comments on Wordpress posts, so that only the post Author can see them, as well as the user who posted the comment?

Eg - Bob creates a post, and Sally, David, and Jimmy log in and comment on it.
As post author, Bob can see all 3 comments,
Sally can only see hers, David can only see his etc.

Steve is another site Author, he can view Bob's post but cant see any of the comments on that post, he can only see comments on his own posts etc...

Admin can see ALL comments on ALL posts.

I found an old plugin, Semi Private Comments, which looks like it would do the trick, but its no longer working or supported. Various code snippets which I have found online here and on other site dont work. Would appreciate any support.

I'm a complete novice at this, so code Snippet would be prefered method of achiving this.